# Unity Container: how to register and resolve many implementations by namespace?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, unity-container

**Context**. Suppose we have the following `IDocument` hierarchy and `IFunctionary` which responsibility is to treat `IDocument`s.

```
interface IDocument { }
interface IOrder : IDocument { }
interface IBill : IDocument { }

interface IFunctionary<TDoc> where TDoc : IDocument { 
    void Treat(TDoc document); 
}
```

Also there is another branching: suppose we have two phases of document treating described by classes `DocumentPreparation` and `DocumentAcceptance`.

```
class DocumentPreparation {
    public DocumentPreparation(
        IFunctionary<IOrder>[] orderFunctionaries,
        IFunctionary<IBill>[] billFunctionaries
    ) { }
}

class DocumentAcceptance {
    public DocumentAcceptance(
        IFunctionary<IOrder>[] orderFunctionaries,
        IFunctionary<IBill>[] billFunctionaries
    ) { }
}
```

**Intention**. I would like to supply all implementations of `IFunctionary<TDoc>` from namespace `Preparation` to `DocumentPreparation` and all implementations of `IFunctionary<TDoc>` from namespace `Acceptance` to `DocumentAcceptance`.

**Question**. How should I tune the *Unity Container* to achieve that?

**What have I tried**. I can retrieve all necessary types and register them with different names or with the same names. But the code `unity.Resolve<IFunctionary<IOrder>[]>("Preparation")` returns all implementations of `IFunctionary<IOrder>` regardless of names they have been registered with. Thus it seems impossible to use simple named registrations to divide implementations in groups.

Answer (score 0):

Finally we have came to the following solution.

At first one registers all implementations (from both namespaces) of the `IFunctionary<TDoc>` interface via `UnityContainerRegistrationByConventionExtensions.RegisterTypes` method.

After that one registers both `DocumentPreparation` and `DocumentAcceptance` classes using something like the following code.

```
container.RegisterType<DocumentPreparation , DocumentPreparation>(
    new HierarchicalLifetimeManager(),
    new InjectionFactory(c => new DocumentPreparation(
        c.ResolveAll<IFunctionary<IOrder>>()
            .Where(f => {
                var typeNamespace = f.GetType().Namespace;
                return typeNamespace != null && typeNamespace == "Preparation";
            }).ToArray(),
        c.ResolveAll<IFunctionary<IBill>>()
            .Where(f => {
                var typeNamespace = f.GetType().Namespace;
                return typeNamespace != null && typeNamespace == "Preparation";
            }).ToArray())
        ));
```

This code snippet should be duplicated for the `DocumentAcceptance` class.

This solution contains obvious advantages and drawbacks.